# Slow In-Memory Collection with ~500 requests/second

Tags: performance, linq, asp.net-core

I have asp.net Core 3.1 API with ~500 requests/second.
And I'm doing pagination in a pure memory-based collection.
the collection is a large ~700K to 1 million items.
I'm only using LINQ "Where", "OrderBy", "Take" and "Skip" which is the simplest pagination approach.
let say that my class looks like this

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime AgeUtc { get; set; }
}
```

```
private IEnumerable<ItemDto> PopulateItems(int? watermark, UiParameters uiParameters)
{
    IEnumerable<ItemDto> items;

    if (watermark.HasValue)
    {
        items = MemoryCacheService.Instance.ReadOnlyItems
            .Where(x => x.Id > watermark)
            .Skip((uiParameters.PageNumber - 1) * uiParameters.PageSize)
            .Take(uiParameters.PageSize);

        return items;
    }

    items = MemoryCacheService.Instance.ReadOnlyItems
        .Skip((uiParameters.PageNumber - 1) * uiParameters.PageSize)
        .Take(uiParameters.PageSize);

    return items;
}
```

My Problem is

- CPU usage in really High
- Caching my endpoint using [Caching Response Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-3.1.) is usually causing **out of memory exception** because of the `watermark` value which causes high randomization in URLs.
- Most HTTP requests are very slow (> ~8 seconds) and sometimes they are failing. (500 requests/second)

I'm sure there is a better way to make it more efficient. Any help :)

**Edit 1**
——————

We did kind of partitioning (in memory) by splitting our collection into smaller lists, and the results are better. But I still believe we are on the wrong path, we tried to use Redis before using the in-memory collection and things become complicated when users grow from 1 to 1.6 million and a lot network exception occurs and things related to Redis stack exchange MultiPlexer. Now, with In memory solution (at least), we are not getting exceptions but it’s slow!
SQL Azure is really expensive! And when we did a load test for our API the SQL went down after 30 or 40 concurrent connections!

**Edit 2**
——————

We modified the implementation above to be like this, the performance becomes much better. but I still believe we make things complicated and this is not best way to do it.

```cs
public class MemoryCacheService {
    ...
    public ImmutableSortedDictionary<int, List<ItemDto>> Items { get; set; }
    public List<ItemDto> ReadOnlyItems { get; }
    ...
}
```

```cs
private IEnumerable<ItemDto> PopulateItems(int? watermark, UiParameters resourceParameters)
{
    IEnumerable<ItemDto> items;

    if (watermark.HasValue)
    {
        // Validate if Watermark smaller than 1st watermark in the list
        var firstKeyValye = MemoryCacheService.Instance.PartitionedReadOnlyItems.First().Key;
        if (watermark < firstKeyValye)
        {
            watermark = firstKeyValye - 1;
        }

        var skipper = (resourceParameters.PageNumber - 1) * resourceParameters.PageSize;
        var cursor = watermark.Value + skipper;
        var startKey = cursor - resourceParameters.PageSize;
        var endKey = cursor + resourceParameters.PageSize;

        // this logic will get two pages and merge values them in a single List
        var patientLocationsPages = MemoryCacheService.Instance.PartitionedReadOnlyItems
                .Where(k => k.Key >= startKey && k.Key <= endKey)
                .Select(s => s.Value)
                .SelectMany(p => p.AsEnumerable());

        items = patientLocationsPages
               .Where(p => p.Id > cursor)
               .Take(resourceParameters.PageSize);

        return items;
    }

    items = MemoryCacheService.Instance.ReadOnlyItems
        .Skip((resourceParameters.PageNumber - 1) * resourceParameters.PageSize)
        .Take(resourceParameters.PageSize);

    return items;
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown any indices built on your table. Also `Take`/`Skip` make no sense without `OrderBy`, SQL queries aren't ordered.

Comment: This is not a Sql query, it’s in memory collection

Comment: What is the type of `MemoryCacheService.Instance.ReadOnlyItems`?

Comment: @NetMage well List<T>

Comment: @NetMage also when I did partitioning solution I used ImmutableSortedDictionary and the Id was the key .. and I used it in “where” statement.

Comment: Can you tell something about the distribution of `Id` versus `watermark`? How sparse is `Id`? Is `Id` unique? How many items are above / below `watermark` or could it be any number?

Comment: @NetMage the watermark represent the last “id” record that I have as a client .. so next call I will start from Id > watermark .. yes Id is unique .. and it’s sql identity but I’m loading the whole records in memory in Startup. And I Have mechanism to invalidate this memory collection on daily basis.

Comment: I think `SortedList<T>` would be a better choice, and should help if `Id` is not too sparse - you could use `IndexOfKey` to find the `watermark` (incrementing by one until you find it) and then use `Skip`/`Take` starting there - which will directly access the `List` elements by index.

Comment: So the `watermark` is always a valid existing `Id`?

Comment: @NetMage that’s totally right. When the watermark is null, then we will keep iterating through all pages .. and in the last page we will give him a watermark (the last/largest id) value in the response (telling him, next time start from here) and if the response is empty then you are up to date. The mobile app will keep checking every hour. And when the watermark value is 1229 .. the app will keep sending, do you any record after 1229 ..

Comment: Can you give some idea of the range of `Id`? I am trying to figure out how sparse it is...

Comment: After doing the deployment on Azure with 6 small frontend instances. Each node was not able to handle more than 25 to 30 requests/second and maybe Azure has some throttling mechanism and queuing HTTP requests to make sure that your servers will not go down because of high CPU usage. But after applying the partitioning technique we were able to handle 75 requests/second. So Instead of fetching data from 1m from a single list, we created a dictionary of lists with key represents the first Id in each list.

Comment: @NetMage I edited my question to apply the `ImmutableSortedDictionary` implementation (please check **Edit 2**)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224251/discussion-between-bunjeeb-and-netmage).

Answer (score 1):

> This is not a Sql query, it’s in memory collection.

Oh boy. This will never work, you're doing linear searches in a database with up to a million elements, 500 times a second?

You need to implement indexing of some sort on top of your collection, even something as simple as recording every 50 id's index in the collection, so you don't have to start from the beginning every time with `.Where(x => x.Id > watermark)`. If it's sorted on `Id`, even a binary search would be better than what you're doing right now.

Comment: You shouldn't split it into smaller lists, because that will require many allocations for enumerators. What you want to do is to store a list of pointers (as indices, not actual pointers) to your existing large list. Ideally though, since you realize how difficult this is, you'd use an already made in-memory SQL database. Entity Framework has first-class support for in-memory Sqlite databases for example, and you'll see instant benefits!

Comment: May you please point to any resource that I read it. I also added an “edit” to my question

Comment: About Entity Framework? Read Microsoft's documentation on it, [it covers everything](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory)!

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain how you are creating your `ReadOnlyItems`, but if you can use a `SortedList<TKey,TValue>` then you can greatly speed up your method.

Add your `Item`s to the sorted list using `Item.Id` as the key.

In my tests with a million random `Item`s with a `Id` spread of 4:1, I get about 0.02 - 0.04 ms with `SortedList` versus 1.2 - 4 ms for first lookup (or about 100 times faster) to about 0.001 ms vs 3.5 ms for subsequent lookups (or about 400 times faster).

Then, you can do:

```
private IEnumerable<ItemDto> PopulateItems(int? watermark, UiParameters uiParameters) {
    IEnumerable<ItemDto> items;

    if (watermark.HasValue) {
        var firstIndex = MemoryCacheService.Instance.ReadOnlyItems.IndexOfKey(watermark.Value) + 1;

        items = MemoryCacheService.Instance.ReadOnlyItems.Values
                .Skip(firstIndex + (uiParameters.PageNumber - 1) * uiParameters.PageSize)
                .Take(uiParameters.PageSize);
    }
    else
        items = MemoryCacheService.Instance.ReadOnlyItems.Values
            .Skip((uiParameters.PageNumber - 1) * uiParameters.PageSize)
            .Take(uiParameters.PageSize);

    return items;
}
```

NOTE: `SortedList<>.Values` implements `IList` and `Skip` and `Take` have special indexed based optimizations for this.

You can use this extension method to covert to a `SortedList` from an `IEnumerable`:

```
public static SortedList<TKey, TValue> ToSortedList<T, TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, TKey> keyFn, Func<T, TValue> valueFn) {
    var ans = new SortedList<TKey, TValue>();
    foreach (var item in items)
        ans.Add(keyFn(item), valueFn(item));
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: `ReadOnlyItems` will be filled from SQL Database using `IHostedService` with a timer on daily basis. And it ok to `lock` during the assignment operation 
`lock(_syncObj) { ReadOnlyItems=newDbItems }` ... sample of ids in the first-ever request 470709, 470710, 470711,.....471708 (this is page 1/749 ... 1000 items per page). and the last page, I will return `timestamp:1222686` which is also the same Id in the last item of this page. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: @bunjeeb Seems like you can convert to `SortedList` easily, but I added an extension method I use just in case...